# How do you remove text from example sets before processing the data?

Tags: regex, text, rapidminer

I am using RapidMiner 5.3.013.  I am reading from an excel file with thousands of rows of worklogs from Remedy.  I want to remove texts based upon the regex `^[A-Z][\w\d/?(# ]+[\w0-9#)]{2}:` then use Process Documents from Data.  So far have not figured out how to do this. I could just probably write VBA, but would like to know how it can be done in Rapidminer.

Answer (score 0):

Having read the Excel data, make sure the field to be processed by the Process Documents operator is set to type text. Do this using the Nominal to Text operator. Inside the process documents loop, split the data into tokens using the Tokenize operator. Use the Filter Tokens operator to remove any tokens you don't want. This operator takes a regular expression as a parameter. Make sure the invert flag is set on this operator to remove the tokens you don't want rather than keep them